# Object Detection and computing distances between camera and object

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I'm not familiar with any Object Detection models such as tensorflow, I'm planning on developing an android app with Tensorflow-lite for my thesis and I'm wondering if it has any APIs for computing object distances, or is it possible to incorporate other algorithms into it. Truly sorry If I sound stupid. I would also like some recommendations on what models to use for object detection and avoidance if possible.

I tried looking for similar questions but no one had answered. But I did find a youtube video for detecting distances between cars however I'm still confused if it can only be applied for specific objects (only certain types e.g. vehicles, people, non-moving objects), and not for the entirety of objects classified (mixed types of objects).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in OpenCV for stereo vision and comuputing a depth map:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html